# Use of Php function file_get_contents

Tags: php, curl

I have to crawl some values from a website. Should I use curl for that or file_get_contents ??

I am getting some warning with file_get_contents at my localhost .

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you provide a short example of your code?

Comment: What warning are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Curl is more preferable, as compared to file_get_contents as you can set headers, request methods like POST or GET, follow redirection etc. So, curl will be advisble

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $data;
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have basic requirements, I would favor `file_get_contents`. If you need to set headers, and request method etc... I would recommend using `curl`.

In your case, I think `file_get_contents` is enough.

Alternatively, you can use `file` which returns an array of lines from the retrieved file. It works with locally accessible files, and also with remote urls. I often find it more convenient to loop over an array of lines, than to deal with the whole file in one block - so this might be your best option.

```
<?php
  foreach(file('http://example.com/the-file.ext') as $line){
    // do something with $line
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) should be just fine for that purpose